# How do you change the value of a cell in excel by clicking on it using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I've scoured google for some time now and I can't seem to find my answer.

I have a cell that says "In Service", once you click on it, using VBA, I want it to change to "Not In Service" and if you click on that again, it'll go back to "In Service". How would you go about doing this?

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: [Oh really?](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+you+change+the+value+of+a+cell+in+excel+by+clicking+on+it+using+VBA%3F&oq=How+do+you+change+the+value+of+a+cell+in+excel+by+clicking+on+it+using+VBA%3F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "In service" Then
        Target = "Out of service"
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Out of service" Then
        Target = "In service"
    End If
End Sub
```